# CNN: What to do when labels are given by a map

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

When fitting a convolutional neural network for an image classification problem, in order to use functions like

```
flow_from_directory()
image_dataset_from_directory()
```

Keras expects the train data to be stored in this way:

```
\data:
   \training
     \class_1
         "imag1.jpg"
         "imag2.jpg"
          ...
     \class_2
         "imag1.jpg"
         "imag2.jpg"
          ...
     ....
```

Instead, I have a dataset with all the images stored in a single folder and a `.json` file which contains a map from the file names to the labels. Something like

```
{"18985.jpg": 0, "43358.jpg": 0, ... "13163.jpg": 1 ....}
```

Is there an efficient way to use this dataset anyway?

Comment: You want to use this files like that or you want a way to turn this into the configuration image_dataset_from_directory expect ?

Comment: you can use dataframe https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_dataframe

Comment: @AlexandreCatalano both the way would be nice

Comment: I tried something tell me if it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution I advise would be to write a script to build the folders for you

step 1 : open the json, and get a list of unique catégories

step 2 : iterate over the list of unique categories et create a folder under training

step 3 : iterate over the json, and copy the file to the right folder (that you created already)

step 4 : load everything using image_dataset_from_directory

Another one would be to use from_generator

```
import json 
  
# Opening JSON file 
f = open('data.json',) 
  
# returns JSON object as  
# a dictionary 
data = json.load(f) 

def gen():
for (image_path, label) in data.items():
   image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(image_path)
   input_arr = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
   yield (input_arr, label)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
     gen,
     (tf.float32, tf.float32),
     output_shapes=([32,256,256,3], [32,5]) # 5 is your number of categories
```

Personnally I'll go with the first one ^^